# How to pass an argument in the function CreateProcess in Win32

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process, multiprocessing

I have an application **hello.exe** which takes input number by command-line argument and generates  `Fibonacci` number. I want to execute this process by function CreateProcess in Win32.

Here is my file hello.c:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int fib(int n) 
    { 
        if (n <= 1) 
            return n; 
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    } 

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int number = atoi(argv[1]);     // Command Line Argument For Input
        int res = fib(number); 
        printf("\nFibonacci no of %d is: %d\n",number ,res);
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiled the above program by : `gcc hello.c -o hello`

Here is my program for Create Process:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string.h>    
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si[1];
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi[1];
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    char getApplicationName[][200] = { "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\process_CLI\\hello.exe" };
    const int NoOfApplication = sizeof(getApplicationName) / sizeof(getApplicationName[0]);

    //char *fibNumber = "10";
    char *fibNumber = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\process_CLI\\hello.exe  10";

    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfApplication; i++)
    {
        BOOL bCreateProcess = FALSE;
        bCreateProcess = CreateProcess(
            getApplicationName[i],
            fibNumber,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            FALSE,
            0,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &si[i],
            &pi[i]
        );
        if (bCreateProcess == FALSE)
        {
            printf("\nProcess %d Creation Failed . Its Error Number: %d\n", i, GetLastError());
        }
        else {
            printf("\nProcess Creation Successful\n");
            //printf("\nProcessId: %d\n", GetProcessId(pi[i].hProcess));
            //printf("\nThreadId: %d\n", GetThreadId(pi[i].hThread));
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(pi[i].hProcess, INFINITE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfApplication; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi[i].hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi[i].hThread);
    }   
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried diffrent method but unable to pass the argument through the function CreateProcess.

Expected Output:

```
Process Creation Successful    
Fibonacci no of 10 is: 55
```

Actual Output:

```
Process Creation Successful
Fibonacci no of 0 is: 0
```

Please suggest me correct approach.

Comment: Because you specified a module name as first parameter, the second parameter will be the command line, excluding the module name. So just `10`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I have tried that also, still getting the same result. Thanks!!

Comment: Have your module to execute first print `argc` and then all parameters.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor by not developing the bad habit of depending on legacy ANSI strings. Don't program in Windows like it's the 1990s, back when we had to support Windows 9x, which lacked Unicode. Call `CreateProcessW` directly with `wchar_t` strings. Use the `wmain` entry point that provides a `wchar_t **` argument list from the native Unicode command line (i.e. `GetCommandLineW`). If your program needs byte strings, manually encode to UTF-8. Then, when you need to pass byte strings to Windows API functions, first decode them back to native UTF-16 wide-character strings.

Comment: Filesystem paths in Windows are Unicode and not limited in any way to the narrow range of the system ANSI codepage (except in Windows 10 if beta UTF-8 support is enabled), so the ANSI API in general makes a mojibake mess of real-world file paths and real-world strings in general, and should be avoided like the plague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you specified a module name as first parameter, the second parameter will be the command line, excluding the module name. So just `10`.

> *lpApplicationName* The name of the module to be executed. The lpApplicationName parameter can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space-delimited token in the lpCommandLine string.
>
> *lpCommandLine* The command line to be executed. The lpCommandLine parameter can be NULL. In that case, the function uses the string pointed to by lpApplicationName as the command line.
>
> If both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by lpApplicationName specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by lpCommandLine specifies the command line.

So either provide a module name plus command line as *lpApplicationName* or as *lpCommandLine*, but not both, or provide the module name as first parameter and the command line as the second.

---

**EDIT** See the comment of Eryk Sun; however, the documentation does not require in this case that a path name with spaces be contained in quotes:

> The *lpApplicationName* parameter can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space-delimited token in the *lpCommandLine* string.
>   If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin; otherwise, the file name is ambiguous. For example, consider the string `"c:\program files\sub dir\program name"`. This string can be interpreted in a number of ways. The system tries to interpret the possibilities in the following order:
>
> **c:\program.exe** files\sub dir\program name
>
> **c:\program files\sub.exe** dir\program name
>
> **c:\program files\sub dir\program.exe** name
>
> **c:\program files\sub dir\program name.exe**

However, since *lpApplicationName* in OP's code is not NULL and since *lpApplicationName* cannot contain command line arguments, *lpApplicationName* does not need to be a quoted string if this name contains spaces.

Comment: No. Most programs expect their argument list to start at `argv[1]`.

Comment: `lpApplicationName` should be used in general if we already know the executable path or need our own custom search instead of the default search that's provided by `CreateProcessW` when only using `lpCommandLine` (e.g. cmd.exe has a custom search that uses the extensions in the `PATHEXT` environment variable). When using `lpApplicationName`, we can shorten the executable name to something like "hello", e.g. `"hello 10"`, in order to avoid quoting, but not omit it. Else if we have a full path for the executable in `lpCommandLine`, then it must be quoted in general to handle spaces in the path.

Comment: The OP failed to properly quote the executable path in `fibNumber`, so the C runtime in the child process, when parsing the command line to create `argv` for the `main` entry point would set `argv[1]` as "Studio". Then the return value of `atoi(argv[1])` is 0.

Comment: `lpApplicationName` is just a file path, the same as would be passed to `CreateFileW`. If it's not fully qualified, the system resolves it -- like any other relative path -- against the process working directory or drive working directory. It should never be quoted.

Comment: Quoting is only a concern for the application name given in `lpCommandLine`. If `lpApplicationName` is used, then `CreateProcessW` itself does not care at all about quoting in `lpCommandLine` because it does not search for the executable. However, the child process still cares about quoting the app name if it contains spaces, and for programs written in C/C++ (or languages that in turn use C such as Python), this is usually the C runtime parsing `argv[0]` per documented [VC++ argument parsing rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/parsing-cpp-command-line-arguments?view=vs-2019).